# Did Democritus of Abdera, Thrace accuse the Jews of sacrificing Greeks in their religious rituals?

Tags: ancient-greece, byzantine-empire

I was on Wikipedia reading about [Blood Libel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_libel) when I came across the following sentence:

> The earliest known antecedent is from a man named Democritus (not [the philosopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democritus)) mentioned in the [Suda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suda),[15]..."

While Wikipedia says that it was NOT Democritus of Abdera, Thrace, on page 1 of the book [*Anti-Semitism and Its Metaphysical Roots*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anti_Semitism_and_Its_Metaphysical_Origi/F_1DBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) (2015), David Patterson says:

> Democritus of Thrace (ca. 460-370 BCE), known for his claim that all matter is composed of atoms, was a rationalist and materialist philosopher who believed that everything happens according to the ineluctable laws of nature. He is also known for his *Maxims*, a volume of deft bits of wisdom for living a virtuous life. And he is known as the first anti-Semite to invoke a blood libel, ..."

And the source given for the blood libel is Joshua Trachtenberg's book "The Devil and the Jews" published in 1983.

On the Jewish Encyclopedia's online entry of [Blood Accusation](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/3408-blood-accusation#3489), it mentions the same Democritus quote about every 7 years, but after that quote it says, "Nothing further is known of Democritus", suggesting that this is not the well-known philosopher who first proposed atomic theory. This entry appears largely copied from the 1925 [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Jewish_Encyclopedia_Volume_3.pdf).

I searched the University of Kentucky's [Suda Online](http://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/sol/sol-cgi-bin/search.cgi) attempting to find the specific quote, and I found the full entry, which you can see in the first revision of this question if you're curious.

Of note is that the entry is for D**a**mocritus, NOT D**e**mocritus; however, I don't know if this could be a simple transcription error.

Also, I found times (in the Suda On Line) when Democritus was mentioned without any descriptors (such as his location or previous accomplishments), as well as at least one other Democritus of Chios. Adding to the confusion is [Pseudo-Democritus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Democritus), as well as [Democrates of Aphidna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democrates_of_Aphidna), and another known [Democrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democrates) who may have been confused with the most well-known Democritus.

So, my question is was the philosopher known for his atomic theory the same person who accused the Jews of human sacrifice, like the aforementioned books say, or was it a lesser-known historical figure, as the Internet seems to believe - or can we even say with any certainty, given the evidence?

*One note to those who may not be familiar with anti-Semitic tropes, the blood libel is false. Jews never have used human blood in their rituals, but this has not stopped communities around the world from scapegoating their problems off onto the Jews, making false claims about their beliefs, leading to violence against the Jews. Wikipedia correctly records these accusations as "libel". I do not believe the comment by Democritus was true, regardless of which Demcritus/ates made the claim.*

Comment: OK, the Suda is a tenth-century Byzantine work. Do you think maybe the antisemitism appeared there?

Comment: There was also [Damocritus of Calydon in Aetolia](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0104:entry=damocritus-bio-1) who was a [strategos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategos), and the Suda says this guy wrote a book on tactics?

Comment: I'm not super comfortable with our site literally hosting the blood libel accusations in question. Linking to them is just fine for discussion purposes. I'd appreciate it if you could link to the text behind the spoiler tag as well.

Comment: Right. That should be obvious to everyone, which is why I think the details of the accusations aren't really germane to the question.

Comment: On second thought, I've removed the spoiler text entirely. Its still in the editing history, or the "curious" can go do the lookup OP did.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia article makes it clear that these accusations are false, given that Wikipedia calls it "libel". I am not trying to support the use of the blood libel, just trying to figure out if Democritus was the one who leveled the accusation, or if we can even say.

Comment: It seems odd to me that quoting historical works is frowned upon on the history stack exchange. The accusations are clearly false and of historical interest only. It seems like we are being a little too sensitive here.

Comment: I added a note explaining that blood libel is false. I thought the Wikipedia article made this clear, but I made it even more explicit in the question.

Comment: @JimmyG. Thanks - I think that resolves my qualms. Appreciate the update.  As I said, it is clear to most of us that these are false, but if it were clear to all of us, then people would stop perpetrating the libel, and that hasn't happened yet.  Add to that people who are educated in non-Western traditions, and I think your edit is prudent.

Comment: Though I don't feel it is the case on this question, I would point out that claiming disbelief in the hate message or holocaust denial posting is a common tactic of the troll/s posting that type of material. I would point you to an excellent post on [Skeptics.Meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4482), where an individual collected many of the arguments made by the recurring troll. Many of these troll postings start with "I don't believe this, but..." type statements. The entire purpose of these hate messages is to get their trash posted and seen. Lets not let it be seen here.

Comment: So, should I have left out the note? It seemed like I was admonished for presenting the Wikipedia in a "neutral" tone, because I thought the Wikipedia page itself discredits the accusations, so I thought I would explicitly deny the veracity of the allegations in a note, and now I am being told my attempt to remove the "neutrality" is evidence of my being on the other side? It was suggested that some SE users may not be familiar with certain racist tropes. The blood libel would be a laughable charge, had it not been one that caused so much harm throughout the centuries.

Comment: No. I was not trying to 'place you on the other side', just trying to educate readers to tactics used by less-than-ingenuous users. *(Personally I would italicize or parenthesize the note to remove it from the content of the questions itself-show that it is editorial content.)*

Comment: @justCal I italicized the note and voted to close that other question. I see what you mean, though.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: David Patterson has confused the philosopher **Democritus** (of Thrace, 4th century BCE) with the historian **Damocritus** (mentioned in the Suda, probably 1st century BCE).

This is a simple matter of following citations. Patterson cites Trachtenberg, who says:

> Probably the oldest report of a ritual-murder charge is from the pen of a pre-Christian writer, Democritus […]<sup>8</sup>
>
> <sub>Joshua Trachtenberg (1943). [*The Devil and the Jews*, p. 126](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177965/page/n143/mode/2up). Yale University Press.</sub>

In [endnote 8 on p. 243](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177965/page/n261/mode/2up), Trachtenberg cites this claim to the following entry in Théodore Reinach:

> **Damocrite.** Historien d’époque inconnue, mais probablement contemporain des Alexandrins [Chærémon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaeremon_of_Alexandria), [Lysimaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysimachus_of_Alexandria), etc.
>
> **60.** — Suidas, *s.v.* Δαμόκριτος ([C. Müller, *Frag. hist. graec.*, IV, 377](https://archive.org/details/fragmentahistor00unkngoog/page/376/mode/2up))
>
> Damocrite, historien. Ouvrages: *Tactique* en deux livres; *Sur les Juifs*
>
> <sub>Théodore Reinach (1895). [*Textes d’auteurs grecs et romains relatifs au judaïsme*, p. 121](https://archive.org/details/textesdauteursgr00rein/page/120/mode/2up). Paris: Ernest Léroux.</sub>

It seems that Trachtenberg (or his typesetter) made a typographical error, and that Patterson neglected to check.

Comment: So, is this Democritus mentioned anywhere else, or is this one mention from him in the Suda all there is?

Comment: As far as I know, that's all there is. There are a couple of other men with the same name: a sculptor ([Pausanias, *Description of Greece* 6.3](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0160:book=6:chapter=3)) and a general ([Paus. 7.13](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0160:book=7:chapter=13)), but neither seems likely to be the historian.

Comment: It's a minor error, too. The difference between the two names comes down to dialect, like the difference between color and colour.